# Displaying items from an External List in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: list, external-list

I was hoping that someone might be able to help me with this little problem.

We currently have a SharePoint site set up for our Intranet and want to display an error message (i.e. a particular service is down). We have generated an External List that draws these messages from a database. However I'm struggling to find the best way to show a single item from this list onto a page, as a usual CQWP won't work with external lists.

Thanks for any help you guys can offer.